# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm getting error when runtime my project.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.olympic/com.prima.olympic.ProductDetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

This is full log :

```
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): Process: com.example.olympic, PID: 17135
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.olympic/com.prima.olympic.ProductDetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at com.prima.olympic.ProductDetail.onCreate(ProductDetail.java:85)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
06-06 23:12:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(17135): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
```

This is my ProductDetail.java

```
public class ProductDetail extends Activity {
Button btnAddtoShoppingList;
Button btnDeleteShoppingList;
TextView detail_productType;
TextView detail_wdh;
TextView detail_volume;
TextView detail_weight;
TextView detail_cont20;
TextView detail_cont40;
TextView detail_pack;
TextView detail_quantity;
TextView detail_colour;
TextView detail_cetegories;
TextView detail_series;
TextView detail_price;
ImageView detail_imageView;

String shown_id, shown_type, shown_wdh, shown_volume, shown_weight, shown_cont20, shown_cont40, shown_pack, shown_quantity, shown_colour, shown_categories, shown_series, shown_price;
String customer_id, error_message ;
    
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_detail);
    
    btnAddtoShoppingList = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddtoShoppingList);
    btnDeleteShoppingList = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteShoppingList);
    SharedPreferences userInformation = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userinfo", 0);
    customer_id = userInformation.getString("customer_id", "none");
    
    detail_productType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_productType);
    detail_wdh = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_wdh);
    detail_volume = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_volume);
    detail_weight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_weight);
    detail_cont20 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_cont20);
    detail_cont40 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_cont40);
    detail_pack = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_pack);
    detail_quantity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_quantity);
    detail_colour = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_colour);
    detail_cetegories = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_categories);
    detail_series = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_series);
    detail_price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_price);
    detail_imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.detail_imageView);
    
    // Get Value from previous activity
    Intent i = getIntent();
    shown_id = i.getStringExtra("shown_id");
    shown_type = i.getStringExtra("shown_type");
    shown_wdh = i.getStringExtra("shown_wdh");
    shown_volume = i.getStringExtra("shown_volume");
    shown_weight = i.getStringExtra("shown_weight");
    shown_cont20 = i.getStringExtra("shown_cont20");
    shown_cont40 = i.getStringExtra("shown_cont40");
    shown_pack = i.getStringExtra("shown_pack");
    shown_quantity = i.getStringExtra("shown_quantity");
    shown_colour = i.getStringExtra("shown_colour");
    shown_categories = i.getStringExtra("shown_categories");
    shown_series = i.getStringExtra("shown_series");
    shown_price = i.getStringExtra("shown_price");
    
    String checkOrigin = i.getStringExtra("from_activity");
    if(checkOrigin.equals("shoppinglist")){
        btnAddtoShoppingList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnDeleteShoppingList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) i.getParcelableExtra("shown_bitmap");

    detail_productType.setText("PRODUCT TYPE: "+shown_type);
    detail_wdh.setText("W x D x H: "+shown_wdh);
    detail_volume.setText("VOLUME: "+shown_volume);
    detail_weight.setText("WEIGHT: "+shown_weight);
    detail_cont20.setText("CONT20: "+shown_cont20);
    detail_cont40.setText("CONT40: "+shown_cont40);
    detail_pack.setText("PACK: "+shown_pack);
    detail_quantity.setText("QUANTITY:"+shown_quantity);
    detail_colour.setText("COLOUR :"+shown_colour);
    detail_cetegories.setText("CATEGORIES:"+shown_categories);
    detail_series.setText("SERIES:"+shown_series);
    detail_price.setText("PRICE Rp "+shown_price);
    detail_imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);        
    
    btnAddtoShoppingList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            addtoShoppingListTask addtoShoppingList = new addtoShoppingListTask();
            addtoShoppingList.execute((Void) null);             
        }
    });
    
    btnDeleteShoppingList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            deleteShoppingListTask deletetoShoppingList = new deleteShoppingListTask();
            deletetoShoppingList.execute((Void) null);
        }
    });
}
```

can anyone tell me where is the error and how to fix it please? if anyone can help i will be so thankful.

Comment: The error will become evident when you understand what a NullPointerException is. Also please use proper Java formatting for your code.

Comment: Please avoid simply copy and pasting your code. Also, do some research before you ask a question. For example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/4230345) might help solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your String `checkOrigin` is `null` thus giving you a `NullPointerException`. This is what is causing it:

```
String checkOrigin = i.getStringExtra("from_activity");
if(checkOrigin.equals("shoppinglist")){
    btnAddtoShoppingList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnDeleteShoppingList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

The String `checkOrigin` is `null` because you are not receiving any value from your `Intent`. This might be because you forgot to pass a value from your previous `Activity`.
However, you can check to see if your String is `null` and if it is, then those actions won't be performed. You would do this by the following:

```
String checkOrigin = i.getStringExtra("from_activity");
if(checkOrigin != null && checkOrigin.equals("shoppinglist")){
    btnAddtoShoppingList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnDeleteShoppingList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Therefore, if `checkOrigin` is null, then those actions won't be performed.

But I would recommend checking the `Activity` that you are receiving the `Intent` from to make sure that you are sending and receiving the `Intent` correctly.

If you want to read more about `NullPointerException`s, have a look at [this question and its answers for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: Thanks dude. Nice guidance

Answer (score 11):

Change `<view> to <View>`, because view is not about empty view. It's for custom view defined through class attr, like below:

```
<view
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
class="com.your.package.YourCustomView" />
```

And you got error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Thanks for the help..!!

Answer (score 0):

checkOrigin is null

```
String checkOrigin = i.getStringExtra("from_activity");
        if(checkOrigin!=null && checkOrigin.equals("shoppinglist")){
            btnAddtoShoppingList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnDeleteShoppingList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```